# Applying Tangent Lines to Log-Scaled Data for Outlier Detection: Seeking Statistical Theories and Models

Tags: mathematical-statistics, data-visualization, outliers, logarithm, pareto-distribution

I've analyzed the view counts for a YouTube channel's videos (just for example), sorting them by views (on the left) and drawing a tangent line to approximate the central trend on a logarithmic scale (on the right).

Each bar represents a video.

This line seems to demarcate videos with typical view counts from those with exceptionally high or low counts. I'm curious if there's a statistical theory or model that supports this type of analysis, perhaps related to identifying outliers or understanding content performance (any data) distribution.

I've often been skeptical of the broad application of the Pareto Principle's 80/20 rule without empirical backing, so I am looking for a more data-specific theory or statistical model that could provide a nuanced understanding of these patterns. What kind of statistical methods or theories could better quantify and support this kind of analysis?

[image: view counts ordered in linear and log scale]

Comment: Assuming the horizontal axis designates all the videos in reverse sorted order, this is a sideways view of the ECDF of the log view counts.  It looks remarkably close to the ECDF of a lognormal distribution.  (The slope of that line, multiplied by $-\exp(-1/2),$ estimates the geometric standard deviation of the view counts.)  You might consider continuing your analysis by fitting a lognormal distribution and exploring how your data might depart from that reference.